# Untethered App immediately dies upon startup; most of the time

Tags: ios, swiftui

**Environment:**
MacOS Catelina v10.15.7 running on a 2009 iMac.
Xcode:Version 12.3 (12C33)

iPhone 6s Plus running iOS 14.3

**Scenario:** Developing SwiftUI/Combine iOS application an an iMac.

What would cause my app to immediately die upon startup during stand-alone (non-tethered); yet runs okay tethered in host Mac (iMac) within Xcode run?

The simulator appears to work okay.

Sometimes all appears to be okay.  
But too many times I end up with an App that mysteriously dies upon startup (within a second).

Question: 1) How do I record the crash if it's stand-alone? and 
2) What could cause such a different behavior on the device versus simulator?

Comment: It’s written into the log, or you can see it in real time in the Console application.

Comment: The device is stand-alone; no log on the Mac.   As for the device, I don't have a console app.  I'll check to see if there's such an app in the App Store.